# R - Print list in file and recover list

Tags: r, file, nested-lists

I have a list that looks like this:

```
> indices
$`48-168`
$`48-168`$`1`
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$`60-180`
$`60-180`$`1`
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$`180-300`
$`180-300`$`1`
[1] 1 2

$`180-300`$`4`
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$`180-300`$`3`
[1] 3
```

I want to print it somehow in a file and then recover the same list later.

I though printing the object given by `unlist(as.relistable(obj))` and use `relist` later but then I do not know how to recover the information from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your data is not particularly well structured, you might want to just use `save()` here, and save the original R list object:

```
save(indices, file="/path/to/your/file.txt")
```

When you want to load `indices` again, use the `load()` function:

```
load(file="/path/to/your/file.txt")
```